# change the data type in the trigger

Tags: postgresql

good day, i try to create a trigger to insert data in my table, the data is contain in csv files and the data type is numeric in the csv but in the table is numeric, i created a auxiliary table for do math operation (serie * 1000), because the value of serie = 23.56 and i need 23560.

My problem is when i try to convert serie the numeric to integer.

```
create table increments (
    date_created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    last_updated timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    id serial,
    serie integer    
);
```

```
create table auxiliary  (
    aux_serie numeric 
)
```

```
create or replace function aux_multiplicar()
returns trigger 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL 
as
$body$
begin 
    new.aux_serie = new.aux_serie * 1000
    and 
    insert into increments (serie) values (new.aux_serie :: integer);
    
    return new;
end;
$body$

create trigger aux_insertar 
before insert
on auxiliary 
for each row
execute procedure aux_multiplicar();
```

I have this error:

```
ERROR: cannot assign a non-composite value to a record type variable
```

Sorry if you don't understand very well, I'm learning English.

Comment: The problem must be that strange `AND` in your function. Replace it with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate statements, separate them with a semicolumn.

```
create or replace function aux_multiplicar()
returns trigger 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL 
as
$body$
begin 
    new.aux_serie = new.aux_serie * 1000;
    insert into increments (serie) values (new.aux_serie :: integer);
    
    return new;
end;
$body$
```

However, because you've changed `new.aux_serie` this will result in 23560.00 being inserted into `auxiliary` which seems incorrect. [Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=36d38f811d898b5b0f80b59060af128f). You probably instead want to simply multiple the value by 1000 and insert it. No cast necessary.

```
create or replace function aux_multiplicar()
returns trigger 
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL 
as
$body$
begin 
    insert into increments (serie) values (new.aux_serie * 1000);
    
    return new;
end;
$body$
```

Which you could do just as well directly, do you need a trigger and an extra table?

```
insert into increments (serie) values (23.56 * 1000);
```

If you really do need an integer and numeric version, consider a generated column.

```
create table increments (
    date_created timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    last_updated timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    id serial,
    serie integer generated always as (serie_numeric * 1000) stored,
    serie_numeric numeric
);
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8baec7559e893fe25f4367f4f099c368).

Or use a view.

```
create view integer_increments as
  select *, (serie_numeric * 1000)::integer as serie
  from increments;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0eff6de6418dd4111ea40b4c65fc452c).